# How to check the existence of a row in SQLite with Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the cursor with the query statement as follows:

```
cursor.execute("select rowid from components where name = ?", (name,))
```

I want to check for the existence of the components: name and return to a python variable.
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to check if it is NULL or if the column exists in the schema at all??

Comment: No, column name is UNIQUE, so I want so select the components with that name, if it exists or not. Sorry I missed some details

Comment: If you've found the solution, you should select an answer to mark this question as Answered. Preferably someone else's answer that pointed you the right way.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Since the `name`s are unique, I really favor your (the OP's) method of using `fetchone` or Alex Martelli's method of using `SELECT count(*)` over my initial suggestion of using `fetchall`.

`fetchall` wraps the results (typically multiple rows of data) in a list. Since the `name`s are unique, `fetchall` returns either a list with just one tuple in the list (e.g. `[(rowid,),]` or an empty list `[]`. If you desire to know the `rowid`, then using `fetchall` requires you to burrow through the list and tuple to get to the `rowid`.

Using `fetchone` is better in this case since you get just one row, `(rowid,)` or `None`.
To get at the `rowid` (provided there is one) you just have to pick off the first element of the tuple.

If you don't care about the particular `rowid` and you just want to know there is a hit,
then you could use Alex Martelli's suggestion, `SELECT count(*)`, which would return either `(1,)` or `(0,)`.

Here is some example code:

First some boiler-plate code to setup a toy sqlite table:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('create table components (rowid int,name varchar(50))')    
cursor.execute('insert into components values(?,?)', (1,'foo',))
```

**Using `fetchall`:**

```
for name in ('bar','foo'): 
    cursor.execute("SELECT rowid FROM components WHERE name = ?", (name,))
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    if len(data)==0:
        print('There is no component named %s'%name)
    else:
        print('Component %s found with rowids %s'%(name,','.join(map(str, next(zip(*data))))))
```

yields:

```
There is no component named bar
Component foo found with rowids 1
```

**Using `fetchone`:**

```
for name in ('bar','foo'): 
    cursor.execute("SELECT rowid FROM components WHERE name = ?", (name,))
    data=cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        print('There is no component named %s'%name)
    else:
        print('Component %s found with rowid %s'%(name,data[0]))
```

yields:

```
There is no component named bar
Component foo found with rowid 1
```

**Using `SELECT count(*)`:**

```
for name in ('bar','foo'): 
    cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM components WHERE name = ?", (name,))
    data=cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if data==0:
        print('There is no component named %s'%name)
    else:
        print('Component %s found in %s row(s)'%(name,data))
```

yields:

```
There is no component named bar
Component foo found in 1 row(s)
```

Comment: hi unutbu, can you be clearer on the python statement after the assignment to data? I am new to Python

Comment: however, the column 'name' in the 'create table components' I have the UNIQUE property, that's important as well. Thanks for sharing codes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: The sqlite3 behavior is the same in Python3 as in Python2. In fact, it applies to any [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant database adapter.  `zip` returns a list in Python2, but a `zip` object in Python3. So `zip(*data)[0]` would become something like `next(zip(*data))` in Python3. For the code posted here, that's the only change required for Python3.

Comment: Also, note that aggregate functions will always return a tuple. E.g.,
`fetchone(min(col))` where false will return `(None,)`   
`fetchall(min(col))` where false will return `[(None,)]`

Answer (score 22):

I have found the answer.

```
exist = cursor.fetchone()
if exist is None:
  ... # does not exist
else:
  ... # exists
```

Comment: I got this to work by first doing `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")`

Answer (score 6):

As both existing answers (your own and @unutbu's) point out, the trick is that you do need to do *some* sort of fetching, after executing the `SELECT`, to check whether there have been any results to the select or not (whether you do it with a single fetch and check for none, or a fetch-all and check for an empty list, is a marginal difference -- given that you mention a `UNIQUE` constraint they're basically equivalent approaches).

For a very direct answer, you could `select count(*) from components where name = ?`, rather than selecting `rowid`, if all you care is whether the given value for name is present or not (as opposed to, caring about what row id it's on, if at all;-).  Executing this select, and fetching the result, gives you `0` if the value is absent, `1` if it's present (no other result is possible given what you mentioned in a comment about the `UNIQUE` constraint on column `name`;-).

Comment: hi Alex, in fact, I want to check if it exists and get the rowid as well. So, that's why I put the rowid in the select statement. Your solution works perfectly well, but in case it exists, I have to do another select to get the results. Could you please give an example of checking with some codes that I can do in order to have some comparisons? (fetch one & check for none v.s. fetch-all & check empty) Sorry I am new to python & sqlite3

Comment: @fx, if you need the rowid then the code in your self-answer is fine and essentially identical to unutbu's (with a test on `if data:` to check for a non-empty list) -- no need for any deep comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can slightly modify previous answers by capturing the result of `cursor.fetchone()` within the condition check and re-use it to extract the result content:

```
# cursor.execute("SELECT rowid FROM components WHERE name = ?", (name,))
if item := cursor.fetchone():
  print(f'Component {name} found with rowid {item[0]}')
else:
  print(f'There is no component named {name}')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
exist = conn.execute("select rowid from rowid where name = ?", (name,)).fetchone()
if exist is None:
    print("Doesn't exist")
else:
    print("Yep exists")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it even shorter...:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()

if row:
  print "row is present"
else:
  print "row is not present"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason mine was showing the "Lock" message was actually due to me having opened an SQLite3 IDE on my Windows and that was the reason it was locked. I assume I was playing around with the DB within the IDE and hadn't saved the changes and therefor a lock was placed.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question