# Login script using Python and SQLite

Tags: python, linux, sqlite, unix, authentication

I'm trying to create a login script using SQLite to store the user data. Any ideas on how to to that? I have research over hours and found nothing of the kind. I would appreciate any help! :)

This is what I got so far:

```
user = raw_input "User:"
pswd = getpass.getpass "Password"

db = sqlite3.connect('/SABB/DATASETS/SENHAS')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT 1 from sabb WHERE usuario = "user"')
('SELECT 1 from sabb WHERE senha = "pswd"')
if c.fetchall() is True:
    print "Welcome"
else:
    print "Login failed"
```

But it always returns Login failed... I want to check the input "user" and the input "pswd" against the database and if they match, return Welcome.

I changed it to:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/SABB/DATASETS/SENHAS')
c = db.cursor()
login = c.execute('SELECT * from sabb WHERE usuario = "user" AND senha = "pswd"')
if (login > 0):
    print "Welcome"
else:
    print "Login failed"
```

But I'm still getting Welcome every time. I also tried "if (login == 1)" but then it only returns Login failed.

Comment: A `fetchall()` will never return `True`.

Comment: @KlausD. and what would?

Comment: Never safe plain text passwords, always save salted hashes. Get a library that does this for you. Under GDPR you're subject to hefty fines for saving plain passwords like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = raw_input "User:"
pswd = getpass.getpass "Password"

db = sqlite3.connect('/SABB/DATASETS/SENHAS')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * from sabb WHERE usuario="%s" AND senha="%s"' % (user, pswd))
if c.fetchone() is not None:
    print "Welcome"
else:
    print "Login failed"
```

First: fetchone() and fatchall() don't return True, but a matching result. We want to use fetchone() because we are interested in one row in the database. If no row is found, fetchone() will return None.

We check if we got a matching result and print Welcome if we do. If fetchone() returns None, it goes to else statement - Login Failed

Here's my test log

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> database = sqlite3.connect("my.db")
>>> db = database.cursor()
>>> Player = "iScrE4m"
>>> Played = 10
>>> db.execute("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name='%s' AND Played='%i'" % (Player, Played))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02D3B3E0>
>>> print db.fetchone()
(1, u'iScrE4m', 1, 1494, 10, 5, 5)
>>> Played = 8
>>> db.execute("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name='%s' AND Played='%i'" % (Player, Played))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02D3B3E0>
>>> print db.fetchone()
None
>>>
```

Comment: that gives me the "Welcome" message every time, even when the username and password is incorrect.

Comment: What does print c get you instead of welcome? When debugging code, it's often good to let it print everything it's getting. It's way easier to spot what it's actually doing that way.

Comment: I get "<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1005e6ef8>"

Comment: Oh sorry, it's probably good idea to create
`result = c.fetchone()` and print result | edit: Just realized. What happens with if c.fetchone() is not None:?

Comment: In that case my edit should do the trick, I'll edit the original answer and try and explain why :)

Comment: I'm still only getting Login failed. Same results as before :/

Comment: what does print return this time?

Comment: None. I was thinking maybe it was a database issue but I can still insert data using a different script...

Comment: I tested it myself and found an issue in the execute command. Current edit worked for me.

Comment: YES! That was it! Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Cheers, sorry it took me a while, first answer on here, next time I'll go straight to testing myself ;)

Comment: it was great! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From how I've read your source code, you're getting the username and password from your user, but not actually using this anywhere. Instead you'll want to substitute the actual username and password in your `WHERE` statements. I believe the code below would be the most pythonic:

```
# Get login details from user
user = input('User: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

# Connect to database
db = sqlite3.connect('path/to/database')
c = db.cursor()

# Execute sql statement and grab all records where the "usuario" and
# "senha" are the same as "user" and "password"
c.execute('SELECT * FROM sabb WHERE usuario = ? AND senha = ?', (user, password))

# If nothing was found then c.fetchall() would be an empty list, which
# evaluates to False 
if c.fetchall():
    print('Welcome')
else:
    print('Login failed')
```

Please note that you should always the method provided by `cursor.execute()` for substituting data entered by a user into a database call. Using the `format()` or `%` substitution method leaves you open to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

### Do not do this:

```
c.execute('SELECT * from sabb WHERE usuario="%s" AND senha="%s"' % (user, pswd))
```

Imagine if someone passed in:

- User =  `Bob`
- Password = `my_cool_password" OR 1=1; --`

The cursor would evaluate:
    SELECT * from sabb WHERE usuario="Bob" AND senha="my_cool_password" 
    OR 1=1; -- ";

It'd allow me to log in as any user. By trivially changing my input I could execute any command on the database that I wish (including deleting a login, adding a login, dropping the entire table etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/SABB/DATASETS/SENHAS')

c = db.cursor()

login = c.execute('SELECT * from sabb WHERE usuario = "user" AND senha = "pswd"')

if (len(login.fetchall()) > 0):
     print "Welcome"
else:
     print "Login failed"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that. The answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440147/how-to-check-the-existence-of-a-row-in-sqlite-with-python

Answer (score -1):

In your second approach, you are checking if a cursor object is greater than 0 rather than checking if the returned list of results has a length greater than 0. Since the variable has some object, the expression will evaluate to `True`.`login` is not a status as you may have assumed.

Your final code should be:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('/SABB/DATASETS/SENHAS')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * from sabb WHERE usuario = 'user' AND senha = 'pswd'")
if (len(list(c)) > 0):
    print "Welcome"
else:
    print "Login failed"
```

Comment: I'm still getting Login failed every time. I checked the databse and the records are correct.

Comment: The code assumes hardcoded values 'user' and 'pswd' for the fields usuario and senha in table sabb that should exist in the /SABB/DATASETS/SENHAS database. Checked it personally, should work without problems.