# Is there a way to speed up database transactions?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

Sorry for the vague question, let me explain...

I have a list of words and counts in a database that has, no doubt, reached a gigantic amount. ~80mb database with each entry being two columns (word, integer)

Now when I am trying to add a word, I check to see if it is already in the database like this...python sqlite3 class method...

```
self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM {tn} WHERE {cn} = """{wn}"""'.format(tn=self.table1, cn=self.column1, wn=word_name))
exist = self.c.fetchall()
if exist:
    do something
```

Comment: Does your table have an index?

Comment: sometimes the index takes more space than the actual table

Comment: @idjaw it does not, I am reading about it now...new to dealing with databases

Comment: What's actually yor question and what does this have to do with transactions?

Comment: sorry if the title used the wrong word, but the question text should explain it, what exactly isn't clear about my question? I am experiencing long wait times with the select statement on a large table

Comment: @deltaskelta "I am experiencing long wait times with the select statement" this is not clear in your question, it isn't even mentioned. Neither is the fact that checking for existence is not enough, as you say in another comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're checking for the existence of a word within a very large table of words? I think the short and simple answer to your question is to create an index for your word column.

The next step would be to setup a real database (e.g. Postgres) instead of sqlite. Sqlite is doesn't have the optimization tweaks of a production database and you'd likely see a performance gain after switching.

Even for a table with millions of rows, this shouldn't be a super time-intensive query if your table is properly indexed. If you already have an index and are still facing performance issues there's either something wrong with either your database setup/environment or perhaps there's a bottleneck in your Python code or DB adapter. Hard to say without more information.

Comment: I dont have an index, and this is what I need I believe. I am new to DB's so I didn't know this before. THanks

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that using `COUNT` within SQL would be faster:

```
self.c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {tn} WHERE {cn} = """{wn}"""'.format(tn=self.table1, cn=self.column1, wn=word_name))
num = self.c.fetchone()[0]
if num:
    #do something
```

though I haven't tested it.

See [How to check the existence of a row in SQLite with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440147/how-to-check-the-existence-of-a-row-in-sqlite-with-python) for a similar question.

Comment: hmm thanks for the input. The problem is that if the row exists, I am going to have to select it anyway. Do you still think it would be faster given I have to do both?